# jenkins windows ssh slave can't access map drives

Tags: windows, ssh, network-shares, jenkins

I have a jenkins setup at office, where jenkins (windows) is connected to slave (windows) over ssh using OpenSSH public private key authentication. The issue I am facing right now is with the access to the map drives on the slave. I have looked over internet for several solutions but could not able to access already mapped drives or map new drives from jenkins onto slave. I tried net use  \shared\folder /user:domainname\user  /p:yes and powershell command New-SmbMapping -LocalPath  -RemotePath  -Persistent:[$true|$false] and New-PSDrive -Name  -Root  -PSProvider FileSystem -Scope [Global|Local] -Persist:[$true|$false]. All these work fine when I run locally on the slave, even though there are mounted I could not access from jenkins master through running my job, as my jenkins pipeline job and builds access these n/w shared drives. I tried all these commands and passed the user/passwords through withCredentials. Everytime I receive the same error message "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated"

BTW the jenkins on slave is not running as a windows service, running the slave.jar through java -jar command when the agent is launched. Also, the domain user is same everywhere used.
When launching the agent using user/password credentials over ssh instead on keys, everything works fine but we got use keys for authentication, which is creating the issue.

I also tried running the groovy script within the job, to execute the net use but everytime a new it goes for approval and had to wait for that, which is not ideal for us

Could not able to figure out solution for this, does anyone have a similar issue being resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying credentials instead of using private/public key authentication?

> where jenkins (windows) is connected to slave (windows) over ssh using OpenSSH public private key authentication.

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/SSH-remote-sessions-on-Windows#double-hop-differences-between-password-and-keybased-auth

> A remote session opened via key based authentication does not have associated user credentials and hence is not capable of outbound authentication as the user. This is by design and goes by the rules of standard Windows security.

Comment: Exactly why I was experiencing a problem when trying to access a Windows share from a build job. Thanks!